# return row in row value using php PDO and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am currently using two tables that look like:

```
tasks(user1, user2)

users(id, name)
```

I am performing the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM tasks 
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON tasks.user1 = u1.id 
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON tasks.user2 = u2.id
```

I am using PHP PDO to execute the query and returning an array which I then encode to json like so:

```
$query = $con->prepare($SQL);
$query -> execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

My problem is that the user2 values overwrite the user1 values in the $result array, is there a way I can return something like:

`[{"user1": {"id": "value", "name":"value"}, "user2": {"id": "value", "name":"value"}}]`

so that each user is a new set of data inside the users key value.

Any thoughts on how to do this? I am fairly new to PDO.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give them different aliases (column names) in the query:

```
SELECT t.*, u1.name as name1, u2.name as name2
FROM tasks LEFT JOIN
     users u1 ON tasks.user1 = u1.id LEFT JOIN
     users u2 ON tasks.user2 = u2.id ;
```

Comment: This returns:
[{"name1": "value", "name2":"value"}] I want it to return all columns in users into the key value, not each one separately

Comment: the problem with this is that there are a lot of columns in the users table and I dont want to have to exract each one manually, I need a way of doing u1.* as name1[*] sort of thing?

Comment: You have to list all the columns separately.  You can get the list of columns using `information_schema.columns` and even use a SQL query to generate the SQL for the query `<colname> as <colname>_1, ` (or whatever).

Comment: can you explain how I can use information_schema.columns to get the SQL to generate the query? I dont want to type them in manually as any column changes would have to be mirrored in the code (not exactly maintainable). thanks.